# phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0 remote ajax call

Tags: ajax, json, cordova

I am developing an app in phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0 and I am having problems with an ajax call to a remote server.

I have done all the default stuff, like added Internet acces, with-listed the domain, but the ajax still get's the 404 header.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-host/bus/app-ajax',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: 'type=data_out',
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(ret_data) {
        alert(ret_data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Ajax error(ajax_helper.get_categorys) xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

> My code has an IP address in the "url" variable of the ajax call, I just changed it here for security reasons.

If I copy the content of my www folder to a website that is on the same host as my PHP respond script(browsers don't allow cross domain ajax calls) than it works. On the device that I am testing if I open a browser I can access the domain, and get the json response, but the app just gives me 404 all the time.

Any ideas on what I can still try to make this work?

Comment: I recreated the project with the verbose "phonegap create" command, added the same code, and it works. Was probably some problems with the old project, because I phonegap in it a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the project with the verbose "phonegap create" command, added the same code, and it works. Was probably some problems with the old project, because I updated phonegap in it a few times.